How to ramp-up the initial current from a battery to a capacitive load?
I want the current to rise slowly, instead of jumping right to the max value, when giving a DC Voltage Bus reference.
In the picture:
Battery current at top, then battery voltage, then DC Voltage at capacitor bus on the other side  of the buck boost circuit.

How to tune PI in such a way, the jump from 0 to -7 A is not so sudden?
Edit : Added cicuit
My buck-boost circuit:

Control PI:


what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Can you provide more context to the circuits involved?

@Jeroen3 added circuit snap to question

@user412839 - Hi, It looks like this question is effectively the same (just with added traces of voltage & current) as your question from yesterday here. Since this one has more info, I have just closed yesterday's one as a duplicate of this one. || If you disagree and yesterday's question is materially different (despite having the same buck-boost & control diagrams), then please reply and explain how it's different & why it won't cause duplicated effort from site members answering both. TY

What you are describing is called "precharge".
It is commonly done in traction battery packs and other large batteries with a high-capacitance load.
It is done by first connecting a resistor (or other current-limiting component) between the battery and the load. After precharge is complete, the battery is connected directly to a load.
For the details, please let me refer you to this paper I wrote. TL;DR: it's much more straightforward that your proposed circuit.

We do precharge the capacitors. ( dc bus). So both the dc bus and battery are more or less at the same voltage. but the moment we enable control to boost the bus to a higher voltage , there is sharp spike in current no matter how much we slow the PI down .

"there is sharp spike in current". That means you didn't do precharge, or at least didn't finish doing it.
